# Grouping records whle filling gaps with zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
1    2280  
3    1250  
5    1245  
9    1258
```

But I need a result like this:

```
1 2280  
2 0  
3 1250  
4 0  
5 1245  
6 0  
7 0  
8 0  
9 1258  
10 0
```

Comment: can manually put numbers like 123456 in column A & C while also have manual values in column B. all is needed to sort it out in column D missing gaps with zero. any formula or your own suggestion to solve it?

Comment: Use something like `IFNA(VLOOKUP(C1, A1..A4, 2, FALSE), 0)` (assuming the first snippet is in `A1..B4`, and you populate `C1..C10` with `1..10`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i get #name? i have a1=1 , a2=3 , a3=5 , a4=9 AND b1=2250 , b2=1250 , b3=1245 , b4=1258 and in c1=1 c2=2 c3=3 c4=4 c5=5 c6=6 c7=7 c8=8 c9=9 c10=10 . its very important for me to solve. thanks

Comment: The [IFNA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626C961-A569-42FC-A49D-79B4951FD461) was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this formula would be easier.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$10,2,FALSE),0)
```

[image]

Comment: soooooooo nice of you. it saved my time and lots of brain work. Thanks in deeeeeeep. may you be delighted :)

Comment: dear harun, can you please provide me your c u n t e ct details? i badly need for an issue in formula

Comment: @Juanhue Oh! sorry I was so busy. My email is harun24hr@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Put these two formulas in D1:E1.

```
=ROW()   '◄ D1
=IFERROR(IF(ROW()<INDEX(A:A, MATCH(ROW(),A:A )+(ROW()>1)-ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(),A:A, 0))), 0, INDEX(B:B, MATCH(ROW(),A:A, 0))), 0)   '◄ E1
```

Fill down as necessary. Copy and Paste Special, Values in place to revert the formula results to their values and delete columns A:C.

[image: stupid_stuff]

Comment: Thanks for putting your valuable time to solve it. glad to see cooperation here